# When would a process raise a signal that causes itself to exit?

Tags: c, unix, process, signals

The cpp documentation states,

> It determines if the child process exited because it raised a signal
>   that caused it to exit

regarding the WIFSIGNALED function. What types of situation would cause the process to do such a thing?

Comment: WIFSIGNALED checks if a process exited because of [any signal](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3ucb/WIFSIGNALED/), not necessarily one it raised itself. The phrasing in your particular man page is just awkward.

Comment: The man page should probably say 'received' instead of 'raised'; that would be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use assertions to ensure your program is correct, a failed `assert` will generate a signal, SIGABRT, that causes the process to terminate.  This is a deliberate case of a program signalling itself.

Accidental causes of signals could be said to include (integer) division by zero (SIGFPE, funnily enough), misaligned memory access (SIGBUS; happens if you use an odd address to access a type that must be aligned on an even address boundary — but not all systems are fussy about it), or accessing invalid memory addresses (SIGSEGV).

Answer (score 1):

There are many signals that can cause this, further, there are a variety of ways a process can exit (i.e. with a core dump, etc.). Check out the man page on [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), specifically the section **Standard signals** to see a table of signals a process can receive and the default disposition for each of those signals. For a list of possible dispositions, check the **Signal dispositions** section towards the top.

I don't mean this as an RTFM response. That man page really does show a neat and concise table for the kinds of signals that can exit a process.

For example, there is:

> SIGFPE        - 8 -       Core -   Floating point exception

Which is sent to the process if it performs a floating point exception, for example a division by zero. This would cause your process to exit with a core dump.